# SWITCH Statement Using VALUE or FORMAT function to convert one of the values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am getting this error when I try to create a measure in Power BI:

Function SWITCH does not support comparing values of type True/False with values of type Text. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT function to convert one of the values.

I am unable to fix this from my end

Here is the DAX measure I am creating:

````
SWITCH (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'vw_OA_dashboard_SSL_Region'[SSL_Abbr] ),
    AND ("Audit", [Company_Filtered] = 1 ), SUM ( vw_OA_dashboard_SSL_Region[open_opportunities] ),
    AND ("BTS", [Company_Filtered] = 1 ), SUM ( vw_OA_dashboard_SSL_Region[open_opportunities] ),
    AND ("C&G", [Company_Filtered] = 1 ), SUM ( vw_OA_dashboard_SSL_Region[open_opportunities] ),
    AND ("CYBER", [Company_Filtered] = 1 ), SUM ( vw_OA_dashboard_SSL_Region[open_opportunities] ),
    AND ("EY-P", [Company_Filtered] = 1 ), SUM ( vw_OA_dashboard_SSL_Region[open_opportunities] ),
    " "
)```
````

Comment: Not sure I understand your `AND` statements. How does a string such as "Audit" (in `AND("Audit",[Company_Filtered]=1`) resolve to a Boolean `TRUE`/`FALSE`)?

Comment: Do I need to add any FORMART function in the AND conditions ?

Comment: But what should be equal to "Audit" in that expression? There's no comparison being made.

Comment: 'vw_OA_dashboard_SSL_Region'[SSL_Abbr] is an slicer in report... So in the slicer we do have the options like Audit, BTS, C&G and CYBER so on.... When ever the user selects the slicer option as Audit and company selected company = 1 then I need to display the Sum of open opp counts in CARD visual only to AUDIT or else it should be blank

Comment: Ok, but the result to be returned is the same in all cases, i.e. `SUM(vw_OA_dashboard_SSL_Region[open_opportunities])`, no matter what slicer choice is made. Doesn't make much sense to me. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, the result is same i.e. SUM(vw_OA_dashboard_SSL_Region[open_opportunities]). 
Any option user selects in the slicer the result is SUM(vw_OA_dashboard_SSL_Region[open_opportunities]) or else it should be blank with empty space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

IF ([Company_Filtered] = 1,
SWITCH (
SELECTEDVALUE ( 'vw_OA_dashboard_SSL_Region'[SSL_Abbr] ),
"Audit", SUM ( vw_OA_dashboard_SSL_Region[open_opportunities] ),
"BTS", SUM ( vw_OA_dashboard_SSL_Region[open_opportunities] ),
"C&G", SUM ( vw_OA_dashboard_SSL_Region[open_opportunities] ),
"CYBER", SUM ( vw_OA_dashboard_SSL_Region[open_opportunities] ),
"EY-P", SUM ( vw_OA_dashboard_SSL_Region[open_opportunities] ),
""
),
"")